# Listeners in forms with JComponents

Tags: java, swing, listener

Right now, when I have a form with many JComponents, mainly JTextFields, JTextAreas, JComboboxes, JCheckBoxes and JButtons and want to control their behaviour, for instance the change of focus after a certain key was released, I do the following:

I put all my components in a JComponent[] and cycle through it, adding the appropriate listener. When an event is registered by said listener, I check with "instanceof" what kind of JComponent fired the event and assign the proper reaction.

I use this method for instance to cycle with VK_ENTER through the form, or to "firePropertyChange(..)" after a DocumentListener fires, or to add UndoRedoListeners and so on.

My question  : is there a better way to do this and if yes, can you explain to me the benefits ?

Comment: If [`FocusManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/FocusManager.html) is not the answer, I don't understand the question.

Comment: FocusManager is a good hint, but my question refers to the general practice of putting all JComponents in an array and cycling through them for every listener and every fired event. It works fine enough, but it feels a bit "uneconomic",so I wanted to know if it is recommended practice, or if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: sounds like you doing something _basically_ wrong (never-ever felt such a desire/need) Take a step back and explain _what_ you want to achieve (vs. describing the problems of a perceived solution)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn´t make my question clear. Puce has understood what I am asking, his reply atleast suggests so. I´ll give it another try : Given a possibly great number and some variety of JComponents on a form, I need to  assign listeners for many different events ; the action beeing executed after an event has been registered often depends on the specific kind of JComponent.At the moment, what i do is described above ( cycling through JComponent[], checking with "instanceof"). Is there a better way (possibly Puce´s?) of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but my question refers to the general practice of putting all
>   JComponents in an array and cycling through them for every listener
>   and every fired event. It works fine enough, but it feels a bit
>   "uneconomic",so I wanted to know if it is recommended practice, or if
>   there is a better way of doing it.

I usually write a custom listener (often as an anonymous class) per type/ instance if I have type/ instance specific behavior so that I can avoid instanceof and other other checks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to customise the focus tranfersal system.

Take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), in particular [Customizing Focus Traversal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal)